# Функция для подсчёта суммы цифр чисел JS. Где именно я допустил ошибку?

Tags: javascript, функции, суммирование

Даны два числа. Необходимо проверить, равна ли сумма цифр первого числа сумме цифр второго числа.
По условию задачи дан уже написанный код, который нужно упростить:

```
let num1 = 234;
let num2 = 531;

let digits1 = String(num1).split('');
let digitsSum1 = 0;
for (let digit1 of digits1) {
digitsSum1 += Number(digit1);
}

let digits2 = String(num1).split('');
let digitsSum2 = 0;
for (let digit2 of digits2) {
digitsSum2 += Number(digit2);
}

if (digitsSum1 == digitsSum2) {
alert('суммы цифр совпадают');
} else {
alert('суммы цифр не совпадают');
}
```

Моё решение:

```
let num1 = 234;
let num2 = 531;
function sumDig(num){
let digits = String(num).split('');
let sum=0;
for(digit of digits){
    sum += digit;
}
return sum;
}
if (sumDig(num1) == sumDig(num2)) {
console.log('суммы цифр совпадают');
}else {
console.log('суммы цифр не совпадают');
}
```

В этом примере суммы цифр переменных совпадают, но консоль выдаёт, что НЕ совпадают! Где я допустил ошибку? Спасибо заранее!))

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться отладкой. Думаю это действенный способ в большинстве случаев

Comment: `digit` - это строка, а при сложении числа и строки получается строка. В исходном примере строка превращалась в число с помощью `Number(...)`. У вас же этот момент куда-то делся

Comment: В частности ваша проблема в том, что вы складываете числа и строки. Вам надо строки (digit) перевести в числа

Comment: Узнать это было легко, как я уже упомянул - с помощью отладки. Или банально написав `console.log(digits);` перед циклом и `console.log('sum:', sum);` перед `return` и посмотрев в консоль..... Осваивайте отладку. Будет жизнь проще

Comment: Перевёл строки в числа и всё как по маслу!)) Спасибо всем за подсказки! Прислушаюсь к совету насчёт освоения отладки! ))